# Using tkinter with Python, is there a way to have several URLs in a Listbox?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I'm new to tkinter and I'm trying to build an application that allows the user to click on different URLs in a list that appears on a window and be prompted to the corresponding websites.

In the following I show a simple test case where I would like the user to be able to access the Google news by clicking on the URL below the voice 'Google news' or the 'Yahoo news' by clicking the URL below the voice 'Yahoo news'.

```py
from tkinter import *
import webbrowser

def weblink(url):
    webbrowser.open_new(url)

list_of_items = ['Google news',
                 'https://news.google.com/',
                 'Yahoo news',
                 'https://news.yahoo.com/']
root = Tk()
lb = Listbox(root)
for item in list_of_items:
    lb.insert(END, item)
    if 'https://' in item:
        lb.bind("<Button-1>", weblink(item))
lb.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

The problem is that as soon as I run the script it opens automatically the webpages without me clicking on the URL that appear in the root window. And even if I click on the URLs nothing happens.

I'm using Python 3.6 on Windows.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if that worked like you think, you are binding the button to the entire listbox, not to one row. So your function needs to sort out which element was clicked and if it's a url or not. This is actually the only way to do it. I will recommend the event ListboxSelect rather than Button-1.

```
from tkinter import *
import webbrowser

def weblink(*args):
    index = lb.curselection()[0]
    item = lb.get(index)
    if 'https://' in item:
        webbrowser.open_new(item)

list_of_items = ['Google news',
                 'https://news.google.com/',
                 'Yahoo news',
                 'https://news.yahoo.com/']
root = Tk()
lb = Listbox(root)
lb.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>', weblink)
for item in list_of_items:
    lb.insert(END, item)
lb.pack()
root.mainloop()
```